# How can one ensure a USB serial/uart interface keeps a consistent name across reboots?

Tags: osx, usb

We have a system with two motors and two lidar sensors hooked up to a rig. We can control these right now and have the ports hardcoded in Python. Everything is hooked up to a Mac Mini running Mac OS.

We will sometimes have issues with the sensors and have to unplug them or reboot the machine. We might have to reboot the machine for other reasons though. (Separate issue).

Between reboots and unplugging/plugging devices back in, the USB ports on the machine change and our hardcoded ports no longer work. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to assign static port names to physical ports on a machine? For example:

```
Port 1: '/dev/tty.usbmodem143401'
Port 2: '/dev/tty.usbmodem143402'
Port 3: '/dev/tty.usbmodem143403'
Port 4: '/dev/tty.usbmodem143404'
```

So at least we can be sure of which port we're using? Or is there a better way to do something like this?

I have tried looking up solutions to assign names and alias these USB ports, but nothing I do seems to work.

Right now we have a config/constants file with ports like this

```
MOTOR_PORT = '/dev/tty.usbmodem143401'
PHONE_LIDAR_PORT = '/dev/tty.usbserial11'
READER_LIDAR_PORT = '/dev/tty.usbserial'
```

This is not ideal. We want to move away from this, or figure out a way to at least guarantee what device is plugged in.

We want to reliably be able to tell which device is plugged into which port at any given time, between reboots etc.

Comment: To do what you want to do, you must discover something unique about each device. Do these 4 devices have unique VIDs and/or PIDs?  Try `lsusb | grep UART`  Do these devices have unique serial numbers?  Try `udevadm info -a -n /dev/<DEVICE> | grep '{serial}' | head -n1`

Comment: lsusb and udevadm doesn't work on Mac. Let me try and see manually

Comment: The vendor etc are all the same. Exact same HW. Not sure if the serial is any different.

Comment: Your best bet is unique serial numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by using Adafruit FTDI TTL serial converters. They have unique serials and never seem to change. This is adequate for us. Thanks all!